# Passing Gatsby Image props from state and GraphQL

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

I am having problems with GatsbyImage from "gatsby-plugin-image" plugin that I could really use some help with.

I have a reusable component that I created like this:

```
<section className={this.props.className}> 
  <div className="flexCol summaryStyles">
    <h3 className="boldStyles">{this.props.title}</h3>
    {this.props.copy}
  </div>
  <div className="imagecontainerStyles">
    {this.props.image}
  </div>
</section>
```

I want to use this reusable component to display different images (inside my src/images folder structure I have a sub folder named "process" where I am going to place multiple images). Inside {this.props.image} I want to pass in a GatsbyImage component like this:

```
{this.state.map((item, index) =>
  <Process 
    key={index}
    className={item.className}
    title={item.title}
    copy={item.copy}
    image={<GatsbyImage image={item.image} alt={item.alt}></GatsbyImage>}
  >
  </Process>
)}
```

I have my state setup like this (I only have one item for now but will have multiple items later):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = [
        {
            className: "flexRow flexRowL",
            title: "EXPLORE",
            copy: <p className="pStyles">I did <strong>user interviews</strong> with people that have food allergies to find out what their experiences have been when eating out, specifically ordering food to go.</p>,
            image: this.props.data.pics.edges[0],
            alt: "Explore UI image"
        }
    ];
}
```

And my GraphQL setup like this:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql `
    query {
        pics: allFile(filter: {relativeDirectory: {eq: "process"}}) {
            edges {
                node {
                    name
                    childImageSharp {
                        id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`
```

The only thing that I'm getting is this:
[Website Screenshot Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEWpt.png)

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and if anyone can help or explain I would really appreciate it. I've read through the documentation available on Gatsby and posts here on StackOverflow but I can't seem to figure it out. This is the first time I am using GraphQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach is valid enough to work but I think you are missing the key data in the GraphQL query to allow Gatsby to print your image. It should be something like:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql `
    query {
        pics: allFile(filter: {relativeDirectory: {eq: "process"}}) {
            edges {
                node {
                    name
                    childImageSharp {
                       gatsbyImageData(
                         width: 200
                         placeholder: BLURRED
                         formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
                       )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`
```

*Note: of course, tweak and customize the placeholders (or remove it if you want)*

You need to fetch the `gatsbyImageData` from the image in order to use it as `image` property in `GatsbyImage` component.

Following that, your data should be always `gatsbyImageData` so:

```
image: this.props.data.pics.edges[0],
```

Should become:

```
image: this.props.data.pics.edges.node[0].childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData,
```

The array is `node`, not `edges` so taking the first element (for now) should be in `node[0]`. Once there, as I said, the needed data is `gatsbyImageData` so you need to keep nesting until you reach it.

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize I was trying to get gatsbyImageData from GraphQL. This is an object inside GraphQL right? I just want to make sure I understand because I am new to GraphQL and it is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Yes, it can be summarized like this :)